# Does a US treasury bond guarantee my return of principal if I don't hold it to maturity?

Tags: united-states, bonds

I've read that a US treasury bond is generally thought to be the safest bond of all, but I'm not sure does a US treasury bond guarantee return of principal if I don't hold it to maturity? If not, why not?

Comment: If you don't hold it to maturity then what do you do with it? There are different types of bonds US treasury issues, with different conditions and guarantees.

Comment: For example, if I'm buying Savings I bond (e.g. $1000), I plan to collect some interest semiannually, but if I see a better opportunity in the future when the interest goes down,  I may sell the I bonds. My question is that if I plan to sell them by then, can I get at least $1000 back? If not, what factors could make me not get my principal back?

Comment: You cannot sell an I-bond. You can only redeem them. If you redeem, you will get the principal (your $1000) back, yes, but you may lose some of the interest.

Comment: What is the difference between selling and redeeming? Why can't I sell but only redeem savings I bonds? Since I can get my principal back, but may lose some of the interest if redeem within less than 5 years, does than mean even if interest rate hikes in the future, my savings I bond will not lose value?

Comment: You can't sell I-bonds because they're not transferable. Redeeming means allowing the government to repay its debt to you prematurely, while selling means transferring that debt to someone else for consideration. The government debt (your bond) doesn't change, you'll get your money back. But selling to someone else (when allowed) depends on the price agreed between the buyer and the seller and may be less than the debt (if interests go up, or the debt is at a risk of default).

Comment: So basically this means savings I bonds are not subject to the bond prices drop when interest rate hikes relation?

Comment: they don't have a price because they cannot be sold. There's nothing to drop.

Comment: What are other types of bonds that you can only redeem but cannot sell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring edge cases like having to transfer it to an ex-spouse during a divorce property settlement… the only way to *not* hold it to maturity is to **sell it**.

But you selling, by definition, requires someone else buying.

And that buyer might not think it’s worth as much as it was when you bought it.

Why would they do that, if US government bonds are so safe?  **Interest rate hikes**.

In order to get a 4% yield on a 1% bond, the selling price *must* fall.  Math Says So.

That’s how you lose money on a US Treasury bond.

Comment: What if I sell them on TreasuryDirect? Do I guarantee at least my principal back if the interest rate hikes in the future? What math are you talking about?

Comment: Does what you were talking about apply to Savings I bonds (bond prices drop when interest rate hikes)?

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld the Treasury Direct web site has a pretty extensive help section.  It’s specific that you cannot sell to the secondary market directly from that site, lays out what can and can’t be sold on the secondary market, and how to transfer bonds from TD to brokerages.

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld let's say there's a $1000 bond out which Bob purchased new back in 2019, and which provides a dividend of $10 per year.  Now (when interest rates are 4%) he wants to sell it.  Will *you* pay $1000 for a "used" bond paying 1% when you can buy a *new* bond paying 4%?  Of course not.  But you would pay... *LESS THAN* $1000 for nominally $1000 bond.  "Math" says how much less you'd pay in order to get a 4% yield on a $1000 bond paying $10/year.